# Whats the difference between /deep/ ::ng-deep?

Tags: css, angular, sass

Could you please tell me, the differences between the below two scss styles?
I didn't get the clear idea about this.

```css
:host {
  display: inline-block;

  /deep/ {
    span {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}

:host {
  display: inline-block;

  ::ng-deep {
    span {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it create any impact If i could used the above two styles in <ng-content>?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main difference is, that `::ng-deep` is supported by SASS, while support for `/deep/` was removed. This is the reason why `::ng-deep` was added to Angular in addition to `/deep/`

Besides that, both are deprecated in Angular, because when native shadow DOM support in all browsers becomes usable, they will probably remove `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`